# PHP: PEAR mail help

Tags: php, email, pear

I'm trying out the mail pear package. It successfully sends an email but give me the following error:

```
Strict Standards: Non-static method Mail::factory() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\ClientPortal\classes\SupportTickets.php on line 356

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\PHP\PEAR\Mail\smtp.php on line 365

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\PHP\PEAR\Net\SMTP.php on line 386

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\PHP\PEAR\Net\SMTP.php on line 391

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\PHP\PEAR\Net\SMTP.php on line 398

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\PHP\PEAR\Net\SMTP.php on line 441

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\PHP\PEAR\Net\SMTP.php on line 230

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\PHP\PEAR\Net\SMTP.php on line 445

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\PHP\PEAR\Mail\smtp.php on line 376

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\PHP\PEAR\Net\SMTP.php on line 526

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\PHP\PEAR\Net\SMTP.php on line 230

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\PHP\PEAR\Net\SMTP.php on line 529

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\PHP\PEAR\Net\SMTP.php on line 532

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\PHP\PEAR\Net\SMTP.php on line 441

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically,  assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\PHP\PEAR\Net\SMTP.php on line 230

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\PHP\PEAR\Net\SMTP.php on line 445

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\PHP\PEAR\Net\SMTP.php on line 550

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\PHP\PEAR\Net\SMTP.php on line 694

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\PHP\PEAR\Net\SMTP.php on line 230

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\PHP\PEAR\Net\SMTP.php on line 698

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\PHP\PEAR\Net\SMTP.php on line 706


Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\PHP\PEAR\Net\SMTP.php on line 230

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\PHP\PEAR\Net\SMTP.php on line 1017

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\PHP\PEAR\Net\SMTP.php on line 415

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\PHP\PEAR\Net\SMTP.php on line 230


Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\ClientPortal\classes\SupportTickets.php on line 364
Message successfully sent!
```

Here's my code:

```
function submitTicket(){

     $from = "Billy Jones <billy.jones@networkroi.co.uk>";
     $to = "helpdesk <helpdesk@networkroi.co.uk>";
     $subject = "Email Test!";
     $body = "email test body";

     $host = "***";
     $username = "***";
     $password = "**********";

     $headers = array ('From' => $from,
       'To' => $to,
       'Subject' => $subject);
     $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
       array ('host' => $host,
         'auth' => true,
         'username' => $username,
         'password' => $password));

     $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

     if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
       echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
      } else {
       echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
      }

}
```

Can some one help me out here?

Comment: Not sure as I normally installed PEAR packages manually, but the Net_SMTP package at least can be found here for manual installation: http://pear.php.net/package/Net_SMTP

Comment: thanks that worked! but now I'm having different errors although the email has been sent successfully! I've updated my question

Comment: Is the email sent? It looks like the method signature of PEAR::isError is lacking the static attribute, which means it will raise an E_STRICT error if accessed static via PEAR::isError. You could update your error_reporting level (either in php.ini or in your php script using ini_set) to E_ALL ^ E_STRICT and see if it works.

Comment: Hehe, great, I should´ve written an answer to this in order to receive the rep points. ;-) Glad it works though. :-)

Comment: This helped me, please don't close the question as I'm sure it will help future googlers with this error, Max should just make his comment an answer,

Answer (score 32):

I asked the same question over here, and found a real solution (instead of masking errors). Read the answer to the question below for more details, but basically just follow the three edits below.

[How to not call a function statically in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22050416/how-to-not-call-a-function-statically-in-php#22050670)

---

Find `php/pear/Mail.php`, go to line 74 and change:

```
function &factory($driver, $params = array())
```

to

```
static function &factory($driver, $params = array())
```

---

Also in `php/pear/Mail.php` go to line 253 and change:

```
$addresses = Mail_RFC822::parseAddressList($recipients, 'localhost', false);
```

to

```
$Mail_RFC822 = new Mail_RFC822();
$addresses = $Mail_RFC822->parseAddressList($recipients, 'localhost', false);
```

---

Find `php/pear/PEAR.php`, go to line 250 and change:

```
function isError($data, $code = null)
```

to

```
static function isError($data, $code = null)
```

Thanks for Amal for showing how to fix this!

Comment: @ekerner It's funny that you should say that... the root of the problem is pear. They moved their repository to github, and abandoned there website library. The updated version of pear is exactly these changes, line by line. So if you end up updating pear, these changes will stick. For some people it's easier to make a few lines of edits, than updating an entire old system. Plus pear has been abandoned for compressor and other libs that do a much better job.

Comment: @Arian Fair enough, good argument. Although if these edits are in the latest update Id suggest simply updating PEAR.

Comment: @MarcF Not really, I used PHP 5.5.12 but i still this problem too

Comment: @skjulikaka I think MarcF meant that this solution works for PHP 5.5 not that this problem is fixed.

Comment: I have installed mail in pear, but I can't find PEAR.php, where is it? omg

Comment: @andrefadila for debian (and perhaps for ubuntu as well) it is in `/usr/share/php` - at least that where it was for me

Comment: In Cygwin, the files are in `/usr/share/pear/`. Use `find /usr -name pear` for other systems.

Answer (score 11):

The strict errors do not prevent the code from working.

Just set the error reporting setting to `E_ALL & ~E_STRICT` and they will magically disappear.

Comment: Is this supposed to work with both php 5.3 and 5.4? In PHP 5.4 E_STRICT is part of E_ALL. I'm using 5.3.9 and the strict error messages is not surpressed when using error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_STRICT). Is it safe to use anyway?

Comment: I am confused by this answer. For some reason when I suppressed the error.  It wouldn't send the email.  Any ideas?

Comment: @RichardW11: Then it's a different problem.

Comment: Same problem as RichardW11, suppressing errors stops the email being sent.... :( If only there was an actual answer for this question

Comment: I feel like there should be a better answer than this, is the Mail package supposed to raise these errors? Would it not be better simply to call it non-statically?

Comment: This does not work for php 5.5. The below fix by Arian does however.

Comment: This is about as good as saying "Turn off the computer, then you will never see errors of any type!"

Comment: The strict errors do prevent the code from working properly in at least one scenario (whether you hide the E_STRICT errors or not). When piping email to PHP and trying to send a return reply, the original sender will receive a bounce back with a blank error message (even though the mail is received by the server) and the return reply does not make it to the original sender.

Answer (score 8):

```
@require_once "Mail.php";
$headers = array ('From' => $from,'To' => $to,'Subject' => $subject);
$smtp = @Mail::factory('smtp', array ('host' => $host,'port' => $port,'auth' => true,
        'username' => $UName,'password' => $UPass));

$mail = @$smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (@PEAR::isError($mail))
{   echo("<p>".$mail->getMessage()."</p>"); }
else
{   echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");  }
```

Look: I used the `@` sign before some of the variables and methods. And with this way you can send email using php5. This is an old aproach, but should work. Though you might be asked about enabling ssl in configuration but that's a piece of cake. Enjoy. And, of course alernate but latest and great technique is using [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org) .

Comment: It would only work if you have no error handler set like so `set_error_handler(function...` if you have it, restore it like so `restore_error_handler();` and then call the troublemaking functions

Answer (score 5):

As of PHP 5, calling a non-static method of another class from within the non-static method of *another* class ist verboten under `E_STRICT`. When the `PEAR_Mail` package was authored, this was a somewhat obscure meta-programming hack in PHP. Thus `PEAR_Mail` is notorious for this.

The method `PEAR::isError()` probably *should* have been a static method, but it's not and assumes an instance context with lots of `$this` thrown around. `PEAR_Mail` calls it statically within its own instance context, so PHP infers the value of `$this`... Which is all kinds of Bad News.

`PEAR_Mail::factory()` *should* be defined as `static` but isn't for reasons known only to the original authors. It will **ALWAYS** generate that "non-static method" warning message until the code is patched.

**Note:** `PEAR_Mail` hasn't been touched since 2010. Please don't use it...! For alternatives, use the Google, Luke!