# sending mail using php and pear on windows

Tags: php, email, smtp, pear

I am trying to send an e-mail using php script but i am getting errors this is my code.i am using xampp netbeans and windows. and i included pear in the php.ini file but still having thies errors any ideas

```
 require_once "Mail.php";
                            
                            $from = "onlinebookstorb@gmail.com";
                            $to = "'$email'";
                            $subject = "Online book store information";
                            $body = "This is your Id '$userID' click <a href =../index.php > here </a> to change to go to the website "; //todo change URL to make it work when it is online

                            $host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
                            $port = "993";
                            $host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                            $username = "onlinebookstoreb@gmail.com";
                            $password = "";

                            $headers = array('From' => $from,
                                'To' => $to,
                                'Subject' => $subject);
                            $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array('host' => $host,
                                        'port' => $port,
                                        'auth' => true,
                                        'username' => $username,
                                        'password' => $password));

                            $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
                            if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
                                echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
                            } else {
                                echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
                            }
```

and this is the errors i am getting :

> Strict Standards: Non-static method Mail::factory() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\OnlineBookStore\Store\Register.php on line 85
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Mail\smtp.php on line 365
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Net\SMTP.php on line 450
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Net\SMTP.php on line 467

Comment: Does the first warning go away if you try: `$smtp =& Mail::factory(...);`  Also see the comments on this post about [PEAR mail help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044996/php-pear-mail-help)

Comment: no it still the same list of error and i checked the php.ini and the  E_STRICT and it is for all

Comment: Changing error_reporting to `E_ALL ^ E_STRICT` should fix the warnings.  You could use `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_STRICT);` at the beginning of that script to only change the error reporting for that particular code.  It is just that the PEAR mail class is not fully updated for PHP5 OOP.  It should be `public static function factory()` instead of `function &factory(` as defined in Mail.php

Comment: can you please specifiy exactly what should i change in the php.ini shoud i change this; Eval the expression with current error_reporting().  Set to true if you want or something else

Comment: In php.ini, you could set error reporting to `error_reporting = E_ALL ^ E_STRICT` or just leave php.ini as it is and add `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_STRICT);` at the top of Register.php.

Comment: i tried everything still same problem

Comment: now i am not getting any errors but the mail is not sending

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem and solved it using:

```
@require_once "Mail.php";
...
$smtp = @Mail::factory('smtp', array('host' => $host,
                                        'port' => $port,
                                        'auth' => true,
                                        'username' => $username,
                                        'password' => $password));
$mail = @$smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
if (@PEAR::isError($mail)) {
```

Notice that I prepended an `@` to all pear / mail calls.

I prefer this solution to changing the general error message settings as I don't want to see the pear / mail warnings but I do want to see the ones that apply to my own code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes jeroens method doesn't show the warning messages, but does it actually solve the problem? apprehending @ just hides the warning associated with it.

To fix the problem in Mail.php modify the following

```
function &factory($driver, $params = array())
```

Change it to

```
static function &factory($driver, $params = array())
```

Reason for this error is because PEAR Mail has not been updated to PHP5 Standards and still uses PHP4 so gradually as servers become PHP5 Compliant this will become more frequent. Its better to fix rather than hide.

Hope this helps