# Sending mail in php using pear

Tags: php, email, smtp, pear

The problem I am facing at the moment is really odd.
I've used the script given below before and it has worked like a charm, but now it is simply not working.

Here is the code:

```
function send($str){
    $from = "body<body@gmail.com>";
    $to = "TargetName <matthew.s@gmail.com>";
    $subject = "Questionnaire Submission!";
    $body = $str;
    $host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $username = "body";
    $password = "pwd";

    $headers = array ('From' => $from,
        'To' => $to,
        'Subject' => $subject);
    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
        array ('host' => $host,
            'auth' => true,
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password));
    $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
    if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
        echo("An error occured during submission! Please try again!");
    } else {
        echo("Submission Successful!!\nYou will now be redirected to a page to fix the timings.");
    }
}
```

Now this code wont send the mail can I cannot understand why.

Some help would be appreciated.

Best Regards
Priyabrata

*edit*

I received a mail from the account I was using to send the mail :

```
This is an automatically generated Delivery Status Notification

THIS IS A WARNING MESSAGE ONLY.

YOU DO NOT NEED TO RESEND YOUR MESSAGE.

Delivery to the following recipient has been delayed:
Message will be retried for 2 more day(s)

Technical details of temporary failure:
Message temporarily rejected.  See http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=69585 for more information.
```

Comment: Insert this after `if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {`: `die($mail->getMessage());` and tell us what the error message says.

Comment: blank.. I do not get any error messages at-all.

Comment: Does adding `error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);` to the top of the page change that?

Comment: How about changing `die($mail->getMessage());` to `die($mail->getCode());`

Comment: no. it still remains blank.

Comment: Sorry for so many questions but until we known the type of error the best answer we can give is general troubleshooting steps.

Comment: not an issue. but cannot understand whats going on.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280829/sending-mail-using-php-and-pear-on-windows?rq=1

Comment: yes, that didn't help.

Comment: You may be experiencing a problem with PEAR mailer being out of date. It has been well behind PHP for awhile now. It may have finally gone completely unusable with the current PHP. You could downgrade your PHP installation to verify this.

Comment: Hmm..Last time around 1 month ago, I used this code with my existing php installation. Don't know what has gone wrong here.

Comment: Still, if you are getting to the line we've been putting these die() commands into then you SHOULD be able to print the value of $mail in some way. Figure that out and you'll be much closer to the problem.

Comment: BINGO!! Kept running the same thing, now I see, 'Validation Failed', with my own login credentials, which I am sure that are correct as I am able to login to my gmail account with it.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with PEAR mail; it's a general email issue.
PEAR's Mail package can send mails fine - also with recent PHP versions like 5.5 and 5.6beta1.

---

Try to send the mail to a different email address, this might work.

Also follow Gmail's guidelines as depicted in the [support URL](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/69585) in your response.

> In situations where the recipient is a Gmail user, we will include:
>
> ...

So send the mail to a gmail address, and you will get more information.