# How to not call a function statically in php?

Tags: php, email, methods, pear

I am using pear to send mail in PHP. I've followed the example that is on here (http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.send.php). However, I am getting this error message.

> **Strict Standards:** Non-static method Mail::factory() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\functions.php on line 43

So I've been trying to get this Strict Standards message to not show up.

This is my code:

```
$smtpinfo["host"] = "********";
$smtpinfo["port"] = "587"; 
$smtpinfo["auth"] = true; 
$smtpinfo["username"] = $mail_username; 
$smtpinfo["password"] = $mail_password; 

## This line below is causing the problem ## 
$mail =& Mail::factory("smtp", $smtpinfo);  // <-- Line 43
```

I've read many [Stack Overflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044996/php-pear-mail-help?rq=1) that say just add a `@` to the beginning of `$mail`. And it is true, it makes the error disappear, but I feel like that just hides the error, and doesn't actually solve the problem.

```
@$mail =& Mail::factory("smtp", $smtpinfo);
```

**How do I not call the method above as statically?**

Even the documentation on this page (http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.send.php), says `This function cannot be called statically.`... but the example they gave is the same way I am calling the method?!

Please don't answer just add `@` in front to remove the strict standard or `E_ALL & ~E_STRICT` ... that is not a solution!

Comment: +1 for actually trying to figure out a solution instead of choosing to hide the error messages using the evil `@` operator.

Comment: In documentation, it says cannot call statically for `send` function. That means, you can not use, `Mail:::send()`. Factory part need to be static

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL good catch... but why is PHP giving me an error about factory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take a look at the PEAR Mail class, you can see that there are a few instances of it calling methods statically when the methods are not declared as static.

Change line 74 of `Mail.php` from:

```
function &factory($driver, $params = array())
```

to:

```
static function &factory($driver, $params = array())
```

The other less desirable alternative would be to modify your `php.ini` configuration to disregard the `E_STRICT` warnings, but I believe fixing the cause of the error message is better than hiding it.

Comment: I updated mail.php as has been suggested in multiple threads however I am still receiving the same errors.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong in your code and example in pear documentation page. That is `non-fatal message` that PHP gives. The main reason of that message is, pear `Mail` has not been updated for the keyword `static`. PHP has been introduced `static` keyword usage in 2006 or 2007, couldn't remember the exact date. PHP gives error about the static calling because of pear `Mail` 's old code base.

Comment: `That is not important message.` - I disagree. Ignoring such error messages leads to PHP being known for low code quality. If you *can* fix something, why shouldn't you?

Comment: @AmalMurali thanks for your warning, I have updated my sentence about that. I couldn't mean actually it is not important.

Answer (score 2):

without any need to modify the original classes, simply create a custom class with a method:

```
class Mailer {
    function sendConfirmationEmail() {
        $ret = false;
        $smtp = new Mail();
        $smtp->factory('smtp', $emailServer);
        $mail = $smtp->send($recipient, $headers, $body);

        if (@PEAR::isError($mail)) {
            sprintf("in sendConfirmationEmail error: %s", $mail->getMessage());
        } else {
            sprintf("in sendConfirmationEmail E-Mail successfully sent to: %s", $recipient);
            $ret = true;
        }
        return $ret;
    }
```

and call it in your static code:

```
$m = new Mailer();
$m->sendConfirmationEmail();
```

It worked for me.
Hope it helps.
Pietro.