# Getting Fatal error: Call to undefined function parseAddressList() while sending email using Pear Mail in PHP

Tags: php, email, gmail, pear

I am completely new to php. I am trying to send an authenticated email using PHP Pear Email system. Whenever I send email using gmail smtp I get following error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function parseAddressList() in C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\pear\Mail.php on line 255

Here is the code of my application

```
<!--
    Sending an email using gmail smtp server, with authentication, ssl version
    eMail With Authentication SSL Version
-->


<?php

// Pear Mail Library
require_once "Mail.php";
require_once "Mail/RFC822.php";

$from = 'me1@gmail.com';
$to = 'me2@hotmail.com';
$subject = 'Hi!';
$body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";

$headers = array(
    'From' => $from,
    'To' => $to,
    'Subject' => $subject
);

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => '465',
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => 'me1@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'password'
    ));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    echo('<p>' . $mail->getMessage() . '</p>');
} else {
    echo('<p>Message successfully sent!</p>');
}


?>
```

Can anybody give suggestions on how I can send authenticated email through gmail, using PHP Pear mail package? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: as you can see, the error refers to a function called `parseAddressList()`, this function can be found in `Mail.php` on line 255, however for some reason it hasn't been defined there properly... you're either missing another file, or haven't properly installed PEAR... if i was you, i'd checkout [their documentation pages](http://pear.php.net/index.php) to gain knowledge of how this is actually done properly...

Answer (score 0):

My Problem is resolved. Thanks for your direction.

I actually made a mistake in Mail.php file. Accroding to another stackoverflow post [PHP: PEAR mail help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044996/php-pear-mail-help)
I pasted the below text in Mail.php

$Mail_RFC822 = new Mail_RFC822();
$addresses = $Mail_RFC822->parseAddressList($recipients, 'localhost', false);

But some how - was missing so the above lines became

$Mail_RFC822 = new Mail_RFC822();
$addresses = $Mail_RFC822>parseAddressList($recipients, 'localhost', false);

which was the cause of bug.

Now I have corrected that and is able to send the emails.

Thanks a lot.