# php: set_error_handler causes Non-static method Mail::factory() should not be called statically

Tags: php

I have the following mail sending function:

```
function SendMailUtf8($to, $subject, $message) {
    require_once "Mail.php";

    $from = "mydomain <myuser@mydomain.com>";

    $host = "mydomain.com";
    $username = "myuser";
    $password = "mypassword";

    $headers = array ('From' => $from, 'To' => $to, 'Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'X-Mailer' => 'PHP/'.phpversion(), 'Reply-To' => 'myuser@mydomain.com', 'Subject' => '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=');
    //this line is where the error is thrown
    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array ('host' => $host, 'auth' => true, 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password));

    $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $message);

    if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
        return "Error: Mail not sent. Message: " . $mail->getMessage();
    } else {
        return "OK";
    }       
}
```

This function gets called properly without any error from everywhere EXCEPT for pages where I have set my own error handling function:

```
function Func_ErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, array $errcontext) {
    if (error_reporting() == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    if ($errno > 0) {
        throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
    }
}
```

with the following error message:

> Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Non-static method Mail::factory() should not be called statically

example code that fails:

```
set_error_handler("Func_ErrorHandler");
$MAILto      = "info@mydomain.com";
$MAILsubject = "subject";
$MAILmessage = "message";

$sRet = SendMailUtf8($MAILto, $MAILsubject, $MAILmessage);
```

If I comment out the `set_error_handler("Func_ErrorHandler");` line, there is no problem. Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

Thank you in advance.

edit: Mail.php https://paste.ee/p/LOyBf

Comment: Thats nothing to do with the error handler its this line `$smtp = Mail::factory(....`

Comment: If you DONT summarize the error message, what is the line number on the error?

Comment: Instantiate an object of class MAIL and then call it as `$mail->factory(...`

Comment: _“If I comment out the set_error_hanlder() line, there is no problem.”_ - that only means that you had your _default_ error reporting set to ignore warnings.

Comment: Pro TIP: Dont develop with `error_reporting` set to zero. Error reporting is there to help you NOT make mistakes

Comment: the error happens on this line: `$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array ('host...`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am not developing with error_reporting set to 0. I am developing with error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT

Comment: ___`the error happens on this line: $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array ('host...`___ Then that is where the fix must go. Like the error says _Non-static method Mail::factory() should not be called statically_ You are calling `Mail::factory` as if it were a statically defined method, **but it is not statically defined**

Comment: Did you also change the version of PHP that you are running this code on at roughly the same time you noticed this error?

Comment: I haven't changed any PHP  version, the problem only appears if I set the custom error handling function `set_error_handler("Func_ErrorHandler");`. If not everything is Okay. Why ?

Comment: Could you show contents of file `Mail.php` ?

Comment: @KarolSamborski https://paste.ee/p/LOyBf

Comment: Are you sure that there is no other class named `Mail` which is required here?

Comment: Maybe you're using/including somewhere some namespaced class. Try to call the factory method like this: `\Mail::factory`

Comment: @NicoHaase Yes, and the problem only occurs if I set a custom error handler. That's what it baffles me

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044996/php-pear-mail-help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error handler works correctly. There aren't any problems with it.

> Non-static method Mail::factory() should not be called statically

This message means the error of STRICT level occurred. And if your error reporting setting excludes errors of this level you won't see anything. For example, if your set `error_reporting` to `E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT` all errors of STRICT level will be excluded. But, your error handler converts all errors to exceptions, therefore, if you enable it than you see an error of STRICT level as an exception.

You have several ways to decide this problem:

1.Make sure you use the latest version from the package and correct file (maybe you another class instead of the expected class). There was this problem earlier but it [was fixed](https://pear.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=18254).

2.You can make the object and use the method as non-static

```
$mail = new Mail();
$mail->factory(/*some parameters*/);
```

3.You can use [error control operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) `@` to suppress any error in the code

```
$mail = @Mail::factory(/*some parameters*/)
```

**But It is the wrong way** that can make more problem because all error will be ignored. I added it for complete information.

4.You can [configure the error handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) to ignore error of STRICT level

```
set_error_handler("Func_ErrorHandler", E_ALL  & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT);
```

Comment: Thank you, great answer